# Hide the Application in Application Manager in Android

Tags: android

I want to hide my **Application** in **Android's**  **Application Manager**.

Is it possible ?

How I can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't give it a MAIN/LAUNCHER activity?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean Settings->Applications->Manage Application, then you can't hide your application from there. Even pre-installed application are listed there (though use cannot do some operation on them, like uninstall or move to sdcard). Ability to hide 3rd party apps from user in this place would be considered as security flow. Somebody could install some malicious app and user couldn't even see it.

If you want to hide your application from Application Launcher, then just do not include `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` in any of your activities. For more read [`Intents and intents-filters`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) and [`Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) documentation.

Comment: Hey, can u pls tell me how to prevent application from uninstalling from application manager.