# How to hide any application in android device without rooting my device?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application. I want to hide any application icon (whatsapp,etc ....) in my android device and I want to start my application by pressing some numbers, for instance 456#. Is there a way to do this?

I know how to hide my app icon but i want to search how to **hide other application** icon.

Plz help me, thanx in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at the below post which gives pointers to hide application icon. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398514/hide-application-icon

Comment: i know how to  hiding own app but i want hide any of the application icon.

Comment: Write a custom launcher and show only those apps which you want to. Hide other apps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to hide or unhide any app is through cmd
you have to only a command and buff.. its done

```
  * for disable in Kitkat
```

String cmd = "pm disable" + packageName;
   Shell.SU.run(cmd);

- for enable in Kitkat

  String cmd = "pm enable " + packageName;

  Shell.SU.run(cmd);

  - for hide in lollipop

  String cmd = "pm hide  " + packageName;

  Shell.SU.run(cmd);
- for Unhide in lollipop

  String cmd = "pm hide  " + packageName;

  Shell.SU.run(cmd);