# Hide Android Apps from drawer

Tags: android, android-intent, system, root

How do I hide an android app from the app drawer

I have read some similar questions and suggests using the Android **PackageManager**. 
I was able to successfully hide them but according to a reply in this link,

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679601/how-to-hide-the-application-from-the-installed-application-list)

It says:

*Keep in mind that this also disables the app, so it will not respond to any more intents etc.*

I think he is right, I am having problems while opening my app from an intent.

Is it possible retain the same app functionalities even if I remove the launcher icon.

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11642671/1777090) works.

Comment: what you exactly want? why u hide app icon? Do you want to show icon after a while?